# Setting Navigation bar background image when UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone is deprecated iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, deprecated, metrics

I'm setting 2 different background images for the navigation bar in my iOS 7 project, depending on the orientation of the device. The code is based on the following example from Apple...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html

Now I've updated to iOS 8 and the landscape image no longer loads. The following Apple page tells me UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone is deprecated...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarPositioning_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013381-CH1-SW2

Does anyone know the iOS 8 way to do this? Some of the normal developer.apple.com pages seem to have been down for most of the day. See the gist of my code is below.

```
@interface cQPMNavigationViewController : UINavigationController
@end  

@implementation cQPMNavigationViewController

 - (void)applyImageBackgroundToTheNavigationBar
{
  UIImage *bgImagePortrait = [UIImage imageNamed:@"portrait_bg.png"];
  UIImage *bgImageLandscape = [UIImage imageNamed:@"landscape_bg.png"];

  bgImagePortrait = [bgImagePortrait resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,bgImagePortrait.size.height - 1,bgImagePortrait.size.width - 1)];
  bgImageLandscape = [bgImageLandscape resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,bgImageLandscape.size.height - 1,bgImageLandscape.size.width - 1)];

  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:bgImagePortrait
                                 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:bgImageLandscape
                                 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self applyImageBackgroundToTheNavigationBar];
}
@end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS8 doesn't follow the concept of Landscape and Portrait orientation changes, and

```
willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

is deprecated in iOS8, one needs to use

```
viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:
```

for more deep insight you need to watch Apple WWDC 2014 video "Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit"

[here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I'll post my solution based on your help in a mo.

Answer (score 4):

I've been able to fix my problem by taking the following code from Apple's "Adaptive Photos" example referenced in the WWDC "Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit" [video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/resources/sample-code/). The original code co-exists in my cQPMNavigationViewController file with the new callbacks, providing legacy iOS support.

```
- (void)updateConstraintsForTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)collection
{
  UIImage *bgImage;

   if (collection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact) {
    bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"landscape_bg.png"];
  } else {
    bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"portrait_bg.png"];
  }

  bgImage = [bgImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,bgImage.size.height - 1,bgImage.size.width - 1)];

  [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:bgImage
                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

- (void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
  [super willTransitionToTraitCollection:newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
  [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
    [self updateConstraintsForTraitCollection:newCollection];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
  } completion:nil];
}
```